# Render directory contents with sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to render the contents of a directory via sinatra's routing dsl

In my browser, I can access the folder like so:

`file:///Users/lfender/source/onesearch/public/bower_components/swagger-ui/dist/`

[image]

using sinatra routes, i'd like to point a route to this static directory:

```
get '/api-docs/' do
  root = File.join(settings.public_folder, 'bower_components', 'swagger-ui', 'dist')
  File.read(File.expand_path(root))
end
```

the above route will fail with `Is a directory @ io_fread` because I am passing in a directory rather than a file.

How do I read contents of static directory via sinatra route so I can serve up files in the public directory using `/api-docs/`? Is this possible with sinatra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - you can serve static assets with the sinatra dsl by accepting the file path as a param:

```
  get '/api-docs/:path_1/:path_2' do
    path = File.join(settings.public_folder, 'bower_components', 'swagger-ui', 'dist', params[:path_1], params[:path_2])
    File.read(File.expand_path(path))
  end

  get '/api-docs/:path' do
    path = File.join(settings.public_folder, 'bower_components', 'swagger-ui', 'dist', params[:path])
    File.read(File.expand_path(path))
  end
```

note, you will likely have to set the appropriate mime/content types to responses

Comment: can you add your full application folder structure (tree) ? once i made something like that. it was actually a web based webm/mp4 player.

Answer (score 2):

Search this http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html for `splat`

```
get '/api-docs/*' do |sub_path|
  path = File.join(settings.public_folder, 'bower_components', 'swagger-ui', 'dist', sub_path)
  File.read(File.expand_path(path))
end
```